# Exploded array is skipping values

Tags: php, arrays

```
// WHEN A TOURNAMENT GETS SUBMITTED TO DATABASE MAKE SURE THE ID IS GRABBED AFTER IT HAS BEEN SUBMITTED
// $Tournamentid = mysqli_insert_id() or $Tournamentid = mysqli_insert_id();
// SET DATA FOR THE PRIVATE MESSAGE TO FOLLOWERS
$defaultP = "x";
$from = $n; // maybe $log_username instead of id
$subject = "New Tournament"; //this can be changed
$message = 'hey, I Just made a New Tournament. <a href="http://localhost/esports/tournament.php?n='.$url_name.'">Click here</a> to view the page. Do not reply to this message as we will not recieve it.'; /// this can be changed can add link to tournament

// GRAB FOLLOWERS LIST FOR THIS PROVIDER
$followArray = mysqli_query ($db_conx, "SELECT followers FROM provider WHERE name='$n'");
while ($followrow = mysqli_fetch_array($followArray)){
       $follower_array = $followrow["followers"];
}

// IF THEY HAVE FOLLOWERS
if ($follower_array != "") {
    $follower_array2 = explode(",", $follower_array);

    // CREATE A LOOP THAT WILL FIRE OFF A PM TO EACH FOLLOWER
    // INSERT PRIVATE MESSAGES FOR EACH SUBSCRIBER INTO PN TABLE USING $VALUE TO ADD THEIR ID
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO pm (receiver, sender, senttime, subject, message, parent)
             VALUES('$value', '$from', NOW(), '$subject', '$message', '$defaultP')"; 
}
```

This is a little auto PM system so when somebody creates a tournament all of there followers are PMed a message about it with a link.

The problem I am having is the fact that it only sends 1 user a pm and that is the last follower of the person who created the event. I know this as I have 3 people following this 1 account and only 1 message is created in the pm system. I need it to send out the amount of messages it needs to send out regardless of the number.

This currently only sends 1 PM out and that is to the last person who is in the array on the database row called `['followers']` so I strongly believe the error in my code is here `foreach ($follower_array2 as $key => $value) {` as it isn't setting values correctly however I could be wrong and probably are wrong but if anyone could help me out i would appreciate it very much.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `while` statement, I believe a `foreach` would work better in this situation. It should look like this:

```
//////////WHEN A TOURNAMENT GETS SUBMITTED TO DATABASE MAKE SURE THE ID IS GRABBED AFTER IT HAS BEEN SUBMITTED
            //////// $Tournamentid = mysqli_insert_id() or $Tournamentid = mysqli_insert_id();
            ///////////// SET DATA FOR THE PRIVATE MESSAGE TO FOLLOWERS
            $defaultP = "x";
            $from = $n; //// maybe $log_username instead of id
            $subject = "New Tournament"; //this can be changed
            $message = 'hey, I Just made a New Tournament. <a href="http://localhost/esports/tournament.php?n='.$url_name.'">Click here</a> to view the page. Do not reply to this message as we will not recieve it.'; /// this can be changed can add link to tournament
            ///////////////////GRAB FOLLOWERS LIST FOR THIS PROVIDER
            $followArray = mysqli_query ($db_conx, "SELECT followers FROM provider WHERE name='$n'");
            ////////IF THEY HAVE FOLLOWERS
            if ($follower_array != ""){
            $follower_array2 = explode(",", $follower_array);
            //////// CREATE A LOOP THAT WILL FIRE OFF A PM TO EACH FOLLOWER
            foreach ($follow_array2 as $follow){
            ////////////////INSERT PRIVATE MESSAGES FOR EACH SUBSCRIBER INTO PN TABLE USING $VALUE TO ADD THEIR ID
            $sqli = "INSERT INTO pm (receiver, sender, senttime, subject, message, parent)
            VALUES('$follow', '$from', NOW(), '$subject', '$message', '$defaultP')"; } }
```

This way, for each follower the person has, it will send them a message.

Comment: My code got edited. I do include a `foreach` the code that is currently posted has been edit by JCOC611 and has taken stuff out so it isn't original now. Why would he do that. Anyway you code does look different to my original code so I will give that ago thank you.

Comment: The code you provided didn't send a single PM however I have solved the problem. it was because my bottom `$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));` was not inside the }} there for it wasn't being ran. Thank you anyway